# -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used `catkin_make` successfully in the past but now whenever i try to use `catkin_make`  i get the following error( as you can see i just created this directory  named "delete", but `catkin_make` is still not working (with this directory or any other directory newly or previously created)):

```
asaad@VAIO:~$ mkdir -p ~/delete/src
asaad@VAIO:~$ cd delete/src/
asaad@VAIO:~/delete/src$ catkin_init_workspace n
usage: catkin_init_workspace [-h] [workspace]
catkin_init_workspace: error: Workspace "/home/asaad/delete/src/n" does not exist
asaad@VAIO:~/delete/src$ catkin_init_workspace 
Creating symlink "/home/asaad/delete/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
asaad@VAIO:~/delete/src$ cd ~/delete/
asaad@VAIO:~/delete$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/asaad/delete
Source space: /home/asaad/delete/src
Build space: /home/asaad/delete/build
Devel space: /home/asaad/delete/devel
Install space: /home/asaad/delete/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/asaad/delete/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/asaad/delete/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/asaad/delete/install" in "/home/asaad/delete/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/asaad/delete/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/asaad/delete/build/test_results
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE 
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.90
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git 
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
--   thread
--   system
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so 
CMake Error: File /home/asaad/delete/src/package.xml does not exist.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/stamp.cmake:10 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:61 (stamp)
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:39 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:95 (catkin_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (catkin_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:112 (message):
  catkin_package() 'catkin' must be listed as a buildtool dependency in the
  package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
asaad@VAIO:~/delete$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222512/---configuring-incomplete,-errors-occurred!/) by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-12-14**:
i think catkin_init_workspace failed, create everything new, perhaps with another name?

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2015-12-15**:
i created a new directory named "del" and the same error occurred.

**Comment by [CMobley7](https://answers.ros.org/users/20654/cmobley7/) on 2016-01-21**:
Asaad Irfan,

I am actually receiving the same error. Did you ever resolve it?

Thank you for any help you are able to give, as well as your time and attention to this matter. Have a great rest of the week.

Very Respectfully,
CMobley7

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2016-02-09**:
CMobley, i reinstalled ROS because i couldnt find any other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of `catkin_init_workspace n` you should use simply:

```
catkin_init_workspace
```

See: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1